# C program executes but ends in "Process returned 2097152 (0x200000) execution time : 12.976 s"

Tags: c

I haven't coded for over 20 years, and I am trying to help someone with some simulation. The program reads two clean CSV files, each one contains a matrix of ints. Then I maximize the correlation between one fixed vector and combinations of elements from the second CVS file.

I have tested the functions to read CVS, the function to calculate the correlation coefficient as well as the function to parse through all possible subsets of a given set. They all work.

However, when I write the final piece of code combining them, the message I receive is "Process returned 2097152 (0x200000)   execution time : 12.976 s" and I do not even understand what that means (I suspect a lack of memory optimization, but really I am clueless). Any help would be appreciated.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<math.h>

    #define File1 "D:\\C\\MatriceQuestions.csv"
    #define File2 "D:\\C\\MatriceQSP.csv"
    #define nocolsQSP 1
    #define nocols 1


    int countrowsCSV (char filepath[])
    {
            FILE *fp = fopen(filepath, "r");

            if (!fp) {
            printf("Can't open file\n");
            return 0;
            }

            char buf[1024];
            int row_count = 0;
            while (fgets(buf, 1024, fp)) {
            row_count++;
            }
            fclose (fp);
            return row_count;
    }

    int countcolsCSV (char filepath[])
    {
            FILE *fp = fopen(filepath, "r");

            if (!fp) {
            printf("Can't open file\n");
            return 0;
            }

            char buf[1024];
            int col_count = 0;
            int i = 0;
            fgets(buf, 1024, fp);

         while (buf[i] != '\n') {
            if(buf[i] == ',')
                col_count++;
            i++;
         }
            fclose (fp);
            return(col_count+1);
    }

    const char* getfield(char* line, int num)
        {
            const char* tok;
            for (tok = strtok(line, ",");
                    tok && *tok;
                    tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n"))
            {
                if (!num--)//
                    return tok;
            }
            return 0;
        }

    //for not standard function strdup
    char *sdup(char *s){
        char *ret = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
        if(ret)
            strcpy(ret, s);
        return ret;
       }

    double pearsonCorrelationCoefficient(int x[], int y[], int n)
    {

        double xbar = 0.0, ybar = 0.0, sx = 0.0, sy = 0.0;
        double corr=0.0;
        int i,j;
        /*compute xbar and ybar */
       for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          xbar += x[i];
          ybar += y[i];
       }
       xbar /= n;
       ybar /= n;

       /* compute standard deviation of x and of y*/
       for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          sx += (x[i] - xbar) * (x[i] - xbar);
          sy += (y[i] - ybar) * (y[i] - ybar);
       }
       sx = sqrt(sx / (n-1));
       sy = sqrt(sy / (n-1));

       /*compute r, the correlation coefficient between the two arrays */
       for( i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
          corr += (((x[i] - xbar)/sx) * ((y[i] - ybar)/sy));
       }
       corr /= (n-1);
       /* print results */
    //    printf("The correlation coefficient of the entered lists is: %6.4f\n", corr);
        return (corr*corr);
    }

    int main()
       {
        //Read QSP file
        char currentfile[100] = File2;
        FILE* stream = fopen(currentfile, "r"); //
        int cols = countcolsCSV (currentfile);
        int rows = countrowsCSV (currentfile);
        char line[1000];
        const char * QSPchar[rows][cols];//
        int QSPint[rows][cols];
        int i,j=0;
        double corr = 0.0;
        int combination = 0;

        //Zero matrix
        for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
            for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
                QSPchar[i][j]=0;
            }
        }


        for(i=0;fgets(line, 1000000, stream) && i < rows;i++){
            for(j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                char* tmp = sdup(line);
                QSPchar[i][j] = getfield(tmp, j);
            }
        }
        //get the CSV data into matrix B
        for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
            for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
                if(QSPchar[i][j]){
                       QSPint[i][j]=atoi(QSPchar[i][j]);
     //                  printf("%d\t", QSPint[i][j]);
                }
                else
                    printf("%s\t", "NULL");
            }
    //          printf("\n");
        }
           fclose (stream);

         int QSP[rows];
         memset(QSP,0,sizeof QSP);
         for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
            for(j=nocolsQSP;j<cols;j++)
                QSP[i]+=QSPint[i][j];;

    /*      for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
                printf("%d\n",QSP[i]);
    */
        //Read questions
        strcpy(currentfile,File1);
        stream = fopen(currentfile, "r"); //
        cols = countcolsCSV (currentfile);
        rows = countrowsCSV (currentfile);
        int spread = cols - nocols;
        int N = pow(2,spread);
        const char * A[rows][cols];//
        int B[rows][cols];
        int TempB[rows];
        double tempCorr = 0.0;
        memset(TempB, 0, sizeof TempB);
        i=0;
        j=0;
        int k=0;

        //Zero matrix
        for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
            for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
                A[i][j]=0;
            }
        }


        for(i=0;fgets(line, 1000000, stream) && i < rows;i++){
            for(j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                char* tmp = sdup(line);
                A[i][j] = getfield(tmp, j);
            }
        }
        //get the CSV data into matrix B
        for(i=0;i<rows;i++){
            for(j=0;j<cols;j++){
                if(A[i][j]){
                       B[i][j]=atoi(A[i][j]);
     //                  printf("%d\t", B[i][j]);
                }
                else
                    printf("%s\t", "NULL");
            }
    //          printf("\n");
        }
        fclose (stream);

        //Loop over the number of parts of the cols (2^spread-1)
       for (i=0;i<N;i++){
            for(j=0;j<spread;j++){
                if(i & (1 << j)){
                    for(k=0;k<rows;k++)
                        TempB[k]+=B[k][nocols+j];
                }
            }
            tempCorr = pearsonCorrelationCoefficient(TempB,QSP,rows);
            if(tempCorr>corr){
                corr = tempCorr;
                combination = i;
            }
            memset(TempB, 0, sizeof TempB);
        }
    printf("\n Correlation: %f\t Combination: %d\n",corr,combination);
    return 0;
    }
```

I use Code::Blocks 20.03 to write, compile and run

Comment: `main` should be declared to return `int`, not `void`.

Comment: Note that `char line[1000000];` *might* be too large for a local variable.

Comment: Sounds like it ran to completion. Maybe add in a few print statements to verify or step through with a debugger.

Comment: Note `for(i=0;fgets(line, 1000000, stream) && i < rows;i++){
            for(j = 0; j < cols; j++){
                char* tmp = sdup(line);
                QSPchar[i][j] = getfield(tmp, j);` is allocating lots of memory.  Each `QSPchar[i][j]` is allocated a buffer of `strlen(line)+1`.  I suspect somewhere code is attempting to write to a failed allocation pointer of `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you for your useful advice. As Johnny Mopp pointed out, the program actually executes but I forgot to return or print anything ... late night. I incorporated all of your comments and the code now runs well. It could certainly be optimized (I see several optimizations myself, in addition to the ones some mention) but it gives the only result I need in a reasonable time (13 sec), so I will leave it at that. Thank you very much to all who have taken time to read it and shared wise comments

Answer (score -1):

This declaration:

```
char line[1000000];
```

Allocates a local array of 1 million bytes (about 1MB) on the stack. I believe that with the default settings of Code::Blocks, there will not be enough space on the stack, because you have a big call stack, with functions having lots of smaller arrays. Consider making it a dynamic array on the heap.